# Reasons for which a graph may be not $k$ colorable?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, graph-colouring, clique

While reasoning a bit on [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14319/natural-clique-to-k-color-reduction), I've tried to identify all the different reasons for which a graph $G = (V_G,E_G)$ may fail to be $k$ colorable. These are the only 2 reasons that I was able to identify so far:

1. $G$ contains a clique of size $k+1$. This is the obvious reason.
2. There exists a subgraph $H = (V_H, E_H)$ of $G$ such that both the following statements are true:

   - $H$ is not $k-1$ colorable.
   - $\exists x \in V_G - V_H\ \forall y \in V_H\ \{x,y\} \in E_G$. In other words there exists a node $x$ in $G$ but not in $H$, such that $x$ is connected to each node in $H$.

We can see the 2 reasons above as rules. By recursively applying them, the only 2 ways to build a non $k$ colorable graph which does not contain a $k+1$ clique are:

1. Start from a cycle of even length (which is $2$ colorable), then apply rule 2 for $k-1$ times. Note that an edge is not considered to be a cycle of length $2$ (otherwise this process would have the effect of building a $k+1$ clique).
2. Start from a cycle of odd length (which is $3$ colorable), then apply rule 2 for $k-2$ times. The length of the starting cycle must be greater than $3$ (otherwise this process would have the effect of building a $k+1$ clique).

> **Question**
>
> Is there any further reason, other than those 2 above, that makes a graph non $k$ colorable?

$\ $
**Update 30/11/2012**

More precisely, what I need is some theorem of the form:

> A graph $G$ has chromatic number $\chi(G) = k + 1$ if and only if...

[Hajós calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haj%C3%B3s_construction), pointed out by Yuval Filmus in his answer, is a perfect example of what I am looking for, as a graph $G$ has chromatic number $\chi(G) = k + 1$ if and only if it can be derived from axiom $K_{k+1}$ by repeatedly applying the 2 rules of inference of the calculus. The Hajós number $h(G)$ is then the minimum number of steps necessary to derive $G$ (i.e. it is the length of the shortest proof).

It is very interesting that:

- The question of whether there exists a graph $G$ whose $h(G)$ is exponential in the size of $G$ is still open.
- If such $G$ does not exist, then $NP = coNP$.

Comment: I will repeat my comment from the question you link to in case you are not aware of the theorem (that everyone thinking about coloring should be) of Erdős:  Given natural numbers g and k, there is a graph with girth at least g and chromatic number at least k.  The girth of a graph is the size of the smallest cycle, meaning that if you have girth at least 3, every maximum clique is of size 2 (every edge is a maximum clique).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger_conjecture_%28graph_theory%29 $\hspace{1.65 in}$

Comment: A simple observation that is often helpful: Each colour class is an independent set. If you can show that there is no large independent set, then you know that you will need lots of colours.

Comment: If there were always a simple reason for graphs to be non-$k$-colorable, the graph coloring problem would not be NP-hard.  Unless P=NP, some graphs are non-$k$-colorable _just because_.

Comment: @JɛﬀE: a reason may be simple, but hard to compute. There's a pretty simple reason why a graph does or doesn't have a $k$-Clique, but it's still NP-hard.

Comment: @LukeMathieson. There is a difference between clique and coloring. 3-coloring is NP-Complete while k-Clique is in P for every fixed value of k.

Comment: @ChandraChekuri, indeed, Clique is only W[1]-complete, whereas $k$-COL is Para-NP-complete, they're drastically different, it's just worth keeping in mind that simple to compute is not the same as simple.

Comment: I should say easy or efficient to compute, rather than simple. It's simple enough to compute whether there's a $k$-clique, just not very fast.

Comment: "If such G does not exist, then NP=coNP." Should not it only imply a much weaker result, that nETH fails? Because shorter than exponential is not necessarily polynomial.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should check the [Hajós calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haj%C3%B3s_construction). Hajós showed that every graph with chromatic number at least $k$ has a *subgraph* which has a "reason" for requiring $k$ colors. The reason in question is a proof system for requiring $k$ colors. The only axiom is $K_k$, and there are two rules of inference. See also [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.30.5879) by Pitassi and Urquhart on the efficiency of this proof system.

Comment: Excellent, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Did not know about Hajos construction previously.

Answer (score 15):

A partial answer, in that I don't know a nice "reason" that can be generalised, but the following graph (shameless nicked from [here](http://math.la.asu.edu/~checkman/Steinberg.html)):

[image: Non-3-colorable graph with no K4 or odd cycle with a completely connected neighbour]

Isn't 3-colorable, but is obviously 4-colorable (being planar), and it contains no $K_{4}$, nor any cycle with a additional vertex connected to all the cycle vertices (unless I'm missing something, but the only vertices connected to a vertex and its neighbour are in the 3-cycles). Taking it further, you could apply a version of rule 2 to get a graph of chromatic number 5.

I would suspect that for any given genus, there's a graph of a certain minimum chromatic number (see the [Heawood conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heawood_conjecture)) that doesn't follow rules 1 or 2. Of course I have no proof other than intuition.

Comment: The Petersen Graph is a smaller example of the same thing. Both the above and the Petersen Graph have $K_4$ _minors_, though, which goes back to the above comment about Hadwiger's.

Comment: The Hadwiger Conjecture though is a necessary condition, but not sufficient, so a graph has chromatic number $k$ iff it has a $K_{k}$ minor *and something else*. As JeffE points out of course, it's likely that the something else is *just because* (in the sense that it's not a simple answer).

Comment: @LukeMathieson: Extremely interesting. Do you have an example of a graph which has a $K_k$ minor and which is $k-1$ colorable?

Comment: Take a $K_{k}$ and subdivide all the edges. The resulting graph is bipartite and thus two color able, but obviously has the complete graph as a minor.

Answer (score 12):

Lovasz found topological obstructions for k-colorability and used his theory to solve Knaser's conjecture. His theorem is the following. Let G be a connected graph, and let N(G) be a simplicial complex whose faces are subsets of V that have a common neighbors. Then if N(K) is k-connected (namely, all its reduced homology groups are 0 up to dimension k-1) then the number of colors needed to color G is at least k+3.

Answer (score 11):

Not having a large independent set can be as important as having a large clique.

An important obstruction for a graph to be non k-colorable is that the maximum size of an independent set is smaller than n/k, where n is the number of vertices. This is a very important obstraction. For example it implies that a random graph in G(n,1/2) has chromatic number at least n/log n.

A more refine obstruction is that for every assignment of nonnegative weights for the vertices   there is no independent set that capture a fraction 1/5 (or more) of the total weight. Note that this also include the "no clique obstructions." LP-duality tells you that this obstruction is equivalent to the "fractional chromatic number" of G being larger than k.

There are also obstructions for k-colorability of a different nature that sometimes go beyond the fractional chromatic number barrier. I will devote a separate asnwer to them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The more refined obstruction binding weights and independent sets is extremely interesting...

Answer (score 11):

Re your reformulation of the question as "More precisely, what I need is some theorem of the form: A graph $G$ has chromatic number $\chi(G)=k+1$ if and only if...":

I don't know whether you will think this is adequately explanatory, but it at least fits the syntax you request: an undirected graph $G$ has chromatic number $\chi(G)\ge k$ if and only if, no matter how you orient the edges of $G$, the resulting directed graph will include at least one directed path of length $k-1$. This is the [Gallai–Hasse–Roy–Vitaver theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallai%E2%80%93Hasse%E2%80%93Roy%E2%80%93Vitaver_theorem).

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely 100% adequate. It perfectly fits the reformulation of the question.